# Plotting several graphs with values extracted from one array

Tags: python, numpy, plot, graph

I have an numpy array, lets say one with 4 rows and 6 (always even number) columns:

```
m=np.round(np.random.rand(4,6))

array([[ 0.99,  0.48,  0.05,  0.26,  0.92,  0.44],
   [ 0.81,  0.54,  0.19,  0.38,  0.5 ,  0.02],
   [ 0.11,  0.96,  0.04,  0.69,  0.78,  0.31],
   [ 0.5 ,  0.53,  0.94,  0.77,  0.6 ,  0.75]])
```

I now want to plot graphs according to the column pairs, in this case

Graph 1: x-values=m[:,1] and y-values=m[:,0]

Graph 2: x-values=m[:,3] and y-values=m[:,2]

Graph 3: x-values=m[:,5] and y-values=m[:,4]

The first two columns are basically a pair of values, the next two are another pair of values and the last two also are a pair of values.

All the graphs should be in the same plot!

I need a general solution for plotting multiple graphs like this with an undefined but EVEN number of columns of the array. Something like a loop!

Hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: So basically you want a for loop ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: you realize that you're rounding it, so your array will just be ones and zeros, right?

Comment: I perhaps dont need a loop. I have tried this out so far and it seems to work but i dont feel very comfortable: plt.plot(m[:,1::2],m[:,0::2],'b',linewidth=2.0)

Comment: @user2539738 My actual array contains values in the range (0,25). The above array is just an example

Answer (score 0):

This gives terrible results with the m arra y you specified, but if it was just a sample and your data is more realistic, the following should do:

```
for i in range(m.shape[1] // 2):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(m[:, 2* i], m[:, 2 * i + 1])
```

If you want all the plots on the same figure, just move the plt.figure() out of the loop:

```
plt.figure()

for i in range(m.shape[1] // 2):
    plt.plot(m[:, 2* i], m[:, 2 * i + 1])
```

Comment: It certainly does, however i forgot to mention all the graphs should be in the same plot!

Answer (score 0):

you can loop on all values of the column pairs

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
i=1
while i<len(m[0]):
    x = m[:,i]
    y = m[:,i-1]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig('placeholderName_%d.png' % i)
    plt.close()
    i=i+2
```

note that I'm starting at 1, and incrementing by two.  this conforms to the example you presented

Comment: len(m[0]) is not very typical of numpy, use m.shape[1] rather. Also, consider using string formatting in savefig/

Comment: @P.Camilleri, I've made this a wiki post; len(m[0]) is unconventional, but works.  as far as the "string formatting" I'm not sure what you mean, can you make those changes to this post?

Comment: yes I know it works, but I think you should strive for standard code, hence my remark. Just edited for string formatting